# Why does the variable "nyFrukt" not print after the timed prompt

Tags: javascript, arrays, document.write

```
var frukt = ["banan", "Äpple", "Apelsin"];


document.write("<p>Din lista med frukt inehåller för närvarande " + frukt + ".</p>");
document.write("<p>Den första frukten i listan är " + frukt[0] + ".</p>");
document.write("<p>Den nya frukten i listan är " + frukt[frukt.length - 1] + ".</p>");
```

//The code above works perfect but the timer thats below doesnt

```
setTimeout(function () { var nyFrukt = prompt("Vad är den nya frukten?"); }, 3000);
```

//The document.write below wont print "nyFrukt"

```
document.write("<p>Den nya frukten i listan är " + nyFrukt + ".</p>");
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript uses function scope, your variable nyFrukt is declared inside an anonymous function used in the setTimeout function, therefore when you attempt to reference it in the following document.write function it's no longer in scope.

Simply declare nyFrukt inside a shared scope and it'll work:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  var nyFrukt = prompt("Vad är den nya frukten?");
  document.write("<p>Den nya frukten i listan är " + nyFrukt + ".</p>");
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Sadly a new problem eloved when I did that.

Comment: Now "nyFrukt" replaces the other lines when the prompt is finished

Comment: You're not really building a DOM, you're outputting arbitrary text to the page. You should learn how to manipulate the DOM using JavaScript, functions such as document.createElement and document.appendChild etc will all help, that is to say document.write isn't the best approach for building a DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

**What you're doing wrong:**

- You're trying to write the answer to the page before you actually ask the question.
- Because of the fact that you create your "nyFrukt" variable inside an anonymous function it's inaccessible from the global scope.

**A modified version of your code:**

```
var frukt = ["banan", "Äpple", "Apelsin"];

document.write("Din lista med frukt inehåller för närvarande " + frukt + ".<br /><br />");

document.write("Den första frukten i listan är " + frukt[0] + ".<br /><br />");

setTimeout(function () {
  var nyFrukt = prompt("Vad är den nya frukten?");

  // Push the result to your "frukt" array.
  frukt.push(nyFrukt);

  // Display the last value of the array.
  document.write("Den nya frukten i listan är " + frukt[frukt.length - 1] + ".<br /><br />");

}, 3000);
```

**JSBin:** http://jsbin.com/xaqohefume/1/edit?js,output

**Links to a few articles I recommend you to read:**

- Arrays: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp
- Scope: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp
- Timing events: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp